# How to newline the printed string from the user in assembly code?

Tags: assembly, input, newline, x86-16

I am trying to newline after each while_loop. For example I input "cat" it will print "catcatcatcatcat..." not "cat/ncat/n..." like in python. I am stuck at this. It would be a pleasure if you can point me at the right path or way. Thanks in advance.

Code that I have tried inserting:

```
MOV dl, 10
MOV ah, 02h
INT 21h
MOV dl, 13
MOV ah, 02h
INT 21h
```

The code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
buff db  26        ;MAX NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ALLOWED (25).
     db  ?         ;NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED BY USER.
     db  26 dup(0) ;CHARACTERS ENTERED BY USER.
.code
main:
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax              

;CAPTURE STRING FROM KEYBOARD.                                    
mov ah, 0Ah ;SERVICE TO CAPTURE STRING FROM KEYBOARD.
mov dx, offset buff
int 21h
                     

;CHANGE CHR(13) BY '$'.
mov si, offset buff + 1 ;NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED.
mov cl, [ si ] ;MOVE LENGTH TO CL.
mov ch, 0      ;CLEAR CH TO USE CX. 
inc cx ;TO REACH CHR(13).
add si, cx ;NOW SI POINTS TO CHR(13).
mov al, '$'
mov [ si ], al ;REPLACE CHR(13) BY '$'.
                     

;DISPLAY STRING.                   
mov ah, 9 ;SERVICE TO DISPLAY STRING.
mov dx, offset buff + 2 ;MUST END WITH '$'.
int 21h

;LOOPING 10x
mov cx, 11
while_:
dec cx
jz end_while
mov ah, 9
int 21h
jmp while_
end_while:
exit:
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h

end main
```

Comment: Where exactly did you try inserting those instructions? Please post the actual code that you're testing.

Comment: I kinda don't know where to insert the new line code. I just search on google how to insert new line in assembly and there`s that. My code is above but it prints catcatcatcat... where I want it to be cat newline cat newline cat newline and so on.

Comment: This morning I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73930743/how-to-print-a-newline-in-a-user-input-string) almost identical question by [Kael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18518217/kael) (your alter ego?) but the question was deleted.

Comment: Ah nooo. But hes my friend and we kinda stuck on the same problem and we both didnt understand the answer. He decided to delete it. Im sorry about that.

Comment: OK, I will repost my answer. You need to insert four new nstructions between `add si, cx        ;NOW SI POINTS TO CHR(13).` and `mov al, '$'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't tell your program that you want a new line after each *while_* loop.
When you input the string **dog**, the memory at **buff** contains `1A 03 64 6F 67 0D 00 00` and after your manipulations it is `1A 03 64 6F 67 24 00 00`.
New line is DOS is provided by CR+LF, **buff** should be like `1A 03 64 6F 67 0D 0A 24`.

```
;CHANGE CHR(13) BY '$'.
mov si, buff + 1  ;NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED.
mov cl, [ si ]    ;MOVE LENGTH TO CL.
mov ch, 0         ;CLEAR CH TO USE CX. 
inc cx            ;TO REACH CHR(13).
add si, cx        ;NOW SI POINTS TO CHR(13).

; Insert the following four lines here:
INC SI          ; To reach CHR(10).
MOV AL,10       ; LineFeed character
MOV [SI],AL     ; Store LF after CR.
INC SI          ; To reach '$' terminator.

mov al, '$'
mov [ si ], al  ; Append CHR(10) BY '$'.
;DISPLAY STRING.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't upvote your answer right now because I don't have enough reps yet.

Comment: For a robust and secure implementation, they should consider the possibility of a maximum sized user input (here it's 25 characters). For trouble free addition of the 2 extra bytes, provisions can be made via `buff db  26, 0, 26 dup(0), ?, ?`.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the `MOV dl, 10 MOV ah, 02h INT 21h MOV dl, 13 MOV ah, 02h INT 21h` before `;capture string from keyboard`.